# what happens when you have a repeating job inside a non repeating job in kettle penaho?

Tags: transformation, pentaho, jobs, kettle

I got a job, which I call SUPER JOB because in it are more jobs that are scheduled to run every 5 minutes.

the super job is only ran once, and I assumed that the super job won't end because under it are neverending jobs scheduled to run every 5 minutes.

but what happened was the super job ended and the subjobs was not even able to run their next iteration.

can someone please explain the behaviour when nesting jobs? do they somehow resemble the structure of loops within a loop?

Comment: I'm guessing you're using the enterprise version and scheduling the jobs with the scheduler that comes up from the Start step? If that's not correct, how are you scheduling SUPER JOB?

Comment: using carte server allows to schedule jobs also

Comment: @Brian.D.Myers im not using the enterprise version, just the free PDI. the super job is not setup with any scheduling actually, it is meant to be started only once.

Answer (score 0):

I guess how you're scheduling it doesn't really matter. Just schedule SUPER JOB to run every 5 minutes.

I don't know what would happen if you scheduled sub-jobs to recur. Never tried that because I'm on CE.

I use pg_agent as my scheduler and launch top level jobs via Kitchen. Works quite well.

One thing you'll have to be aware of is what happens if the run of one pass through SUPER JOB takes more than 5 minutes. I'd be very careful of running that frequently unless you really know how your jobs perform.

Comment: yeah, I ditched the idea of using a super job to run all the sub jobs. I just called them one by one via command line. thay way, i think it will be a bit easier to debug and find out what jobs would have problems. calling the jobs using kitchen makes them have a log file for each one and i guess that's a bit better when debugging.

Comment: I've never had a problem with debugging sub-jobs (well, not a serious one). The thing is, you can't keep running jobs forever with just PDI CE. You need a scheduler. You might get it to work, but it won't be pretty. It's best to use an external scheduler. That's why PDI gives you a scheduler when you pay the money for the supported version. Why not try pgAgent?

Comment: hi Brian, thanks for giving me an idea of what else I can use. I haven't heard of pgAgent before but i'll definitely look at it.

Comment: It's an add on to PostgreSQL. You'd need to install PostgreSQL, pgAgent, and pgAdmin, but they're all free and pretty darned good. BTW, pgAdmin is so you can administer the jobs and schedules, pgSQL so pgAgent can store its job defs.

Comment: seems like a lot of work but this should be worth it, and this route can be better from what we are using currently (windows task scheduler). thanks for the tips man. :D

Comment: Yeah, it's more work than Windows scheduler, but once it's set up it's wayyyy better, especially if you have to setup complicated schedules. Just be aware, you'll likely have to reference network shares by UNC names, not mapped drives.